# Saving as array in opensearch

Tags: python, opensearch

I need to save the value as array,

```
    def push_to_opensearch(data):
       """ just for testing in localhost hosted opensearch"""
       index_name = 'new_index_name'
       url = f"https://localhost:9200/{index_name}/_doc/"
       auth_credentials = HTTPBasicAuth('admin', 'BSOIT2020')
       response = requests.post(url, json=data, auth=auth_credentials, verify=False)
       print(f" response from local opensearch {response.text}")
```

Example data

```
    {
         'id': 693103, 
         'platform': ['PlayStation 4, Cassette Recorder']
    }
```

Currently, OpenSearch will save it as `PlayStation 4, Cassette Recorder`. What I want is to save it as `['PlayStation 4', 'Cassette Recorder']`

The mapping looks like this

```
 {
    ......
    "platform": {
       "type": "keyword",
       "ignore_above": 200
     }

  },
```

If I change it to

```
   {
     'id': 693103, 
     'platform': ['PlayStation 4', 'Cassette Recorder']
    }
```

Only the first element is saved.

Any ideas

Answer (score 0):

The correct format is

```
   {
      'id': 693103, 
      'platform': ['PlayStation 4', 'Cassette Recorder']
   }
```

However, when using Query Workbench, it will just show the first element, but using dev tools query, it will show the correct data